# How to get different values of same column in two rows in one row multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
 execution_plan_id  test_case_name      results

     37             LandingPage.test    SKIPPED
     38             LandingPage.test    SKIPPED
```

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBzvC.png)

I want a query which will show the results in below format.

```
test_case_name      results for 37    result for 38

LandingPage.test      SKIPPED           SKIPPED
```

The problem is,  there can be multiple rows with different execution_plan_id. So i want a query which will dynamically create a column. Also i will pass execution_plan_id in where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select test_case_name,
 max(case when execution_plan_id = 37 then results end) result_37,
 max(case when execution_plan_id = 38 then results end) result_38
from my_table
group by test_case_name;
```

Comment: Hello Gurwinder, 

Above query works well for execution_plan_id 37 and 38 , but the problem is there can be multiple rows with different execution_plan_id. 

I want to pass execution_plan_id in where clause.

Comment: Turning rows into arbitrarily many columns is not a good practice. What exactly is your goal? I may be able to advise something based on that